How do I Install pytorch without GPU dependencies?
I have a project that depends on torch==2.0.1, but it will run on CPU not GPU. torch has some large cuda/cublas/cudnn dependencies that I believe are only needed when running on GPU. These packages, which I don't believe I need, account for ~4.5 GB of by ~6.5 GB image.
How can I install torch without installing the GPU specific dependencies? I'm using poetry 1.8.2 to install packages in my Linux 6.6.22-linuxkit x86_64.
I tried ARG CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" in my Dockerfile before running poetry install hoping that these dependencies would not be installed, but that didn't work. I know that env variable is more of a runtime thing that tells torch to use CPU, but the packages have already been install by runtime. I though I'd just try setting it in my Dockerfile just for the heck of it.
NEW TEXT BELOW AS OF 2024.07.29 ~12:12 PM GMT
I know about cpuonly and other ways if torch is a direct dependency. Problem is that it is a dependency of a direct dependency, so I can't do it directly.

From the pytorch website - you can install the CPU only version with:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
or
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch

Thanks for the response Karl. I updated my question above. I def didn't give enough context. Hopefully there is enough now
